# I am connecting to a WiFi or a Hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, router

It's a doubt basically!!

Consider if I am asking a friend to turn on Hotspot then I am turning on WiFi connecting to that phone.

Now consider in case of router, if I am connecting to that router but people say I am connecting to a WiFi and not Hotspot?¿?¿

Then what is created by a router, WiFi or Hotspot?

It's a confusion!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a Wi-Fi conection and a Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34080/whats-the-difference-between-a-wi-fi-conection-and-a-wi-fi-hotspot)

Comment: My intention was not to duplicate others question!!

Comment: It may be that you overlooked that question, unintentionally. If that Q doesn't meet your needs, you can always [edit] your question and clarify so that it is not closed as duplicate

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the English language, not about Android.

Answer (score 1):

A Hotspot is simply a space where a device (an access point) is hosting a Wi-Fi. When it is in public we call it public [Wi-Fi] hotspot. When it is for private individuals only it is simply Wi-Fi to us.  Either way, the difference is in the name only.

When you ask a friend to create a hotspot, you are asking them to host a Wi-Fi using their mobile device. When their Wi-Fi *also* provides internet access through mobile data, than we simply call that *mobile hotspot*. Either way, that is still a Wi-Fi to your device as much as the Wi-Fi created through a router.